# Perl's fields.pm warning: Name "module::FIELDS" used only once

Tags: perl

While using the Net::OpenID::Consumer module, I get a few warnings from the fields pragma.

```
Name "module::FIELDS" used only once
```

investigating a bit, I found that this pragma is traversing the inheritance tree recursively, and looking for FIELDS. however, if that module is using Exporter, for example, and fields happen to look on Exporter only once, it trigger this warning.

Also, out of four warnings, three are actually base classes of other classes, (e.g. Exporter, Tie::Hash) but the fourth is 'Cache::RemovalStrategy::LRU', that for some reason includes:

```
use fields qw();
```

Apparently, it triggers fields to investigate the module, but not to create the FIELDS hash

So, how do I get rid of these warnings?

Edit: using Perl 5.10.0 on MacOSX
Edit: Fixed module name Net::OpenID => Net::OpenID::Consumer

Answer (score 2):

There is no Net::OpenID module (though there are a number of modules under that namespace).

Please show the code that you are running?

Comment: oops. I haven't noticed that these are separated modules.. I am using Net::OpenID::Consumer - fixed in the question

Comment: and does just a simple `perl -we'use Net::OpenID::Consumer'` cause the warning?  if not, please condense your actual code down to the minimum that still gives the warning

Comment: I'd really like to help track this down.